# Enum vs. concrete classes to denote an object type

Tags: c#, oop, enums

Basically, I need to implement a resources (gold, steel, etc.) functionality and their quantity, and I am wondering if it is better to use a single resource class with resourceType field or it is better to use many ConcreteResource classes that inherit Resource. Here are some examples for better understanding of my question:

Using enum:

```
class Resource
{
    private ResourceType resourceType;
    private int quantity;
}

enum ResourceType
{
    ConcreteResource1,
    ConcreteResource2
}
```

Using concrete classes:

```
abstract class Resource
{
    private int quantity;
}

class ConcreteResource1 : Resource
{       
}

class ConcreteResource2 : Resource
{
}
```

Comment: To me: if they are fundamentally of the same type of object, but vary slightly in usage, an enum is sensible. If the objects vary to a significant degree, completely separate classes would be better.

Comment: This isn't really the right place to ask this question.  You might want to consider http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Another option: use a class `ResourceType` instead of an enum.

Comment: Given example doesn't denote any problem. They both will work. `enum` is plain and simple, but you may need inheritance and interfaces in certain design (which you didn't share). Use `enum` if it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the use of the objects.

There are a lot more features obtained by using classes:

1. It can be inherited,
2. It can have methods,
3. It can have properties, fields etc...

So, in general, if your objects aren't alike in their methods, variables, interfaces, etc, (that is, they are two **quite different objects**) you should use `class`. But if your objects are **nearly identical** except for the "type", then `Enum` should be sufficient.

In your example, suppose the two metals are used quite differently, one has set of methods [A1,A2,...,An], and another [B1,B2,...,Bm], then it is best if they are distinguished by `class` perhaps inheriting from the same `MetalBase` class.

However, if they are used almost identically, then you should consider using `Enum`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me, I guess I overcomplicate things too much :)